# Prior to the end of Goblet of Fire, are we ever told how Dobby got in to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, dobby

It's pretty obvious that he used the elf equivalent of apparation, but are we ever actually told that? Is any comment made at all about how he found his way in?

Ever since the scene in *Goblet of Fire* where Crouch's means of disappearance are discussed, I've been finding more and more loopholes in the excuses based around not being able to apparate in Hogwarts. I'm looking to see if we knew anything about how Dobby cheated that rule back in the second book. It's quite odd to me that Dobby's impossible appearances never raised any character's eyebrows after they learned of the "you cannot apparate in Hogwarts" rule.

Comment: Elf magic is different from human magic

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Yes, that's obviously how Dobby cheated, but are we told that this early on?

Comment: Probably something in either Chamber of Secrets or Prisoner of Askaban

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, British edition, Apparition isn't mentioned even once.

[image: Apparition results on Chamber of Secrets]
[image: Apparate results on Chamber of Secrets]

In the American edition, Apparition is mentioned, but it isn't related to elf magic. ¡Thanks @Pam for the link!
https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2001/10/29/differences-british-us-versions-cs/

In Prisoner of Azkaban and Goblet of Fire it is mentioned, but nothing related to elf magic or Dobby Apparating in Hogwarts.

---

I don't recall this topic being explicitly stated until Deathly Hallows, where Harry asked Kreacher how did he leave the cursed Horrcrux cave, and he is surprised that he was able to Dispparate, until Ron reminds him that elf magic is different and they're able to Apparate in Hogwarts when wizards can't.

> ‘But … you couldn’t Apparate in and out of that cave,’ said Harry, ‘otherwise Dumbledore –’
>
> ‘Elf magic isn’t like wizard’s magic, is it?’ said Ron. ‘I mean, they can Apparate and Disapparate in and out of Hogwarts when we can’t.’
>
> <sub>Rowling, J.K.. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (p. 157). Pottermore Publishing. Edición de Kindle.</sub>

Comment: It is mentioned in Chamber of Secrets, but only in the American versions.

Comment: [This](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2001/10/29/differences-british-us-versions-cs/) implies apparition is indeed in some versions of CoS but not in relation to elves.

Comment: @Pam Thanks for the link! I took the liberty of adding it to the answer

Comment: Handy, I've added a bounty for more detail.

Comment: Seems strange that it's not mentioned in the non-American versions